# Error on codeacademy labs writing python script

Tags: python

this is my first attempt at coding a game with python. I am at trying to run it through codeacademy labs but it says this:

```
File "<stdin>", line 7
    __init__(self, name, size_v, size_h): 
^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax Unknown error.
```

don't be afraid of hurting my feelings I am a very novice coder and I know I'm probably making quite a few mistakes.

I supposed I'm also looking for an explanation or alternative on how to code and experiment in a different setting (i think it's called an IDE)

```
from datetime import datetime

log = open("log.txt", "a")


class Ocean(object):
    __init__(self, name, size_v, size_h):
        self.name = name
        self.size_v = size_v
        self.size_h = size_h

class Ship(object):
    __init__(self, size):
        self.health = size
        self.size = size

class BattleShip(Ship)
    __init__(self):
        self.health = 4
        self.size = 4

class AirCarrier(Ship)
    __init__(self):
        self.health = 6
        self.size = 6

class MedicShip(Ship)
    __init__(self, size):
        self.health = 2
        self.size = 2

class ArmouredShip(Ship)
    __init__(self, size):
        self.health = 3
        self.size = 2

def create_user_profile(username):
    user_profile = open(username + "prof", "r+")

def create_default_ocean(name):
    ocean = Ocean(name, 20, 20)
    return ocean.populate(2,1,1,1)

def mainload():
    gametime = datetime.now()
    gamestate = "mainmenu"

    username = str(raw_input("What is your name? "))
    create_user_profile(username)

    gametype = str(raw_input("What do you want to play?     (QUICKPLAY) (CUSTOM)"))
    log.write("[] " + gametime + " [] " + gamestate + " [] " + username + " [] " +gametype")

quick = "quick quickplay qp q"
custom = "custom cust c"

mainload()
if gametype.lower() in quick:
    ocean = create_default_ocean(newocean)
elif gametype.lower() in custom:
    #get height/width of ocean
    #get amount of ships/size
```

Comment: You forgot `def`. To define a function or method, write `def methodname(...)`, e.g. `def __init__(self, size):` above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's 4 kind of errors in your script:

1. You forget the `def` identifier before each function:

   ```
   class Ocean(object):
       def __init__(self, name, size_v, size_h):
     # ^^^
           self.name = name
           self.size_v = size_v
           self.size_h = size_h
   ```

   See [documentation examples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) to get the syntax of classes :)
2. You forget some semicolons after class definition

   ```
   class MedicShip(Ship):
                      # ^ this one
   ```
3. You also have a syntax error in the last function (mainload), there's a quote at the end. The correct line is:

   ```
   log.write("[] " + gametime + " [] " + gamestate + " [] " + username + " [] " +gametype)
   ```
4. Finally, if you want to execute your code, you'll need to put something (other than comments) in the `elif` block at the end of your file. Otherwise, the interpreter will raise a syntax error (`EOF` error). Put a [`pass` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) if you don't want to put any code for the moment:

   ```
   elif gametype.lower() in custom:
       pass     # <- do nothing but create a correct block for the elif
       #get height/width of ocean
       #get amount of ships/size
   ```

I recommend you to read some beginner Python tutorial to learn the syntax ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should define your function `__init__()` by writing def `__init__(self, size)`
also in some places you have forgotten to put ':' after defining class.

- If you are a beginner in python u can get tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)(official python documentation)
- To practice some basic programming stuff go to [www.codingbat.com](http://www.codingbat.com/)